# Eventbus relay error: Encryption not supported in Offcore Runtime

Tags: platform-event, encryption, aws

I've tried setting up the new Salesfoce -> AWS Eventbridge integration using the new event bus relay.

This is the guide I followed: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/Salesforce_Event_Bus_Relay_Pilot.pdf#h.z63eim1tqkm3

However, when testing the event relay, the event relay status is ERROR.

Full error message:

> The configured event relay encountered an error. More details = [ EventBusException: 403::Feature not supported: Encryption not supported in Offcore Runtime ].

What could be causing this? I'm no salesforce expert ;)

Comment: At what step are you seeing this error? Do you have any further details on the CloudWatch logs?

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting this 403 "encryption not supported" error because you are using platform encryption / field encryption via Shield in the org.

Shield is not supported yet for Event Relay (but should be soon). See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/event-relay/guide/feature-support.html

"These features aren’t supported with Event Relay.

- Platform event and change data capture event encryption at rest with Shield Platform Encrypt"

Comment: @identigral updated my answer with the reference detailing why I think he's getting the error.